# Bad Allocation in pointer

Tags: c++

Why I am receiving a Bad Alloc in `new_node->_value = value;`?

```
template<typename K>
struct Node{
    Node<K>* _next=nullptr;
    K _value;
};

template <typename K>
class LinkedList{
public:
    void put(K value)
    {
        Node<K>* new_node;
        new_node->_value = value;
        ...
    }
private:

    Node<K>* _node = nullptr;
};
int main() {
    LinkedList<int> linked;
    linked.put(4);
}
```

I am clueless right now

Comment: `new_node` is not initialized. What do you expect to get when you dereference it?

Comment: `new_node` is just a pointer. You never set it to point to an actual `new_node`.

Comment: You did not allocate new_node. It is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: You are right thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    Node<K>* new_node;
    new_node->_value = value;
```

`new_node` is not initialized pointer. It should be initialized before dereference (allocate memory, assign address of already existed node, assign already existed pointer to node, do something more complex, etc).

For example you can do simply this:

```
Node<K>* new_node = new Node<K>();
new_node->_value = value;
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, well, that's true. But here we are talking about linked list. Anyway, edited.